# Find angle between every row of a raster and matrix (or two matrices) in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a raster with three bands and a matrix with three columns.

```
library(raster)
#Make two single band raster with random values
r1 <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900)
set.seed(42)
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))
r2 <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900)
set.seed(123)
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))
r3 <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, xmn=-1000, xmx=1000, ymn=-100, ymx=900)
set.seed(543)
values(r3) <- runif(ncell(r3))
#Stack them into a three-band raster
r <- stack(r1, r2, r3)

#Make a matrix with values    
y <- matrix(ncol=3, nrow=2, seq(1,6,1))
```

I want to find the angle between every row of y and every cell of r.

```
#Function for angle
    specAngle <- function(a,b){
        acos(sum(a*b)/( sqrt(sum(a*a))*sqrt(sum(b*b))))
    }
```

I can convert the raster to a matrix by:

```
m <- getValues(r)
```

Now each has matrix has the same shape (3 columns in each with each row as a pixel or sample from y).  I have looked at using a nested apply() function but I honestly do not understand the syntax and can't get it to work because of that.

I have 40+ very large hyperspectral rasters (425 bands) and a 50 row matrix that I need to use to generate 40+ new rasters with 50 bands each.  How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this

```
x <- lapply(1:nrow(y), function(rownr) calc(r, function(i) specAngle(i, y[rownr,])))
s <- stack(x)
```

Or written as a loop

```
x <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(y)) {
    x[[i]] <- calc(r, function(j) specAngle(j, y[i,]))
}  
s <- stack(x)
```

You can also rewrite specAngle so that it can compute all rows at once (and returns a vector) and you won't need a loop/lapply